# Async Task with RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, wcf-ria-services, ria, .net-4.5

I´m using Silverlight wich talks to a .net 4.5 server with WCF RIA Services.

I´m interested in using the new Async pattern to gain some performance boost on the server. But when I make some function return async Task on the server then it will not be visible in the Silverlight Client.

Is this not possible with RIA Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Among others, the proxy generator it's not aware of the async pattern and will not generate the needed task-based overload methods client-side.